# Linux Kernel Preemption Levels

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm wondering what the difference between PREEMPT_NONE and PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY are.  According to the documentation,

```
This option reduces the latency of the kernel by adding more
"explicit preemption points" to the kernel code
```

But it does not mention what these points are.  I tried googling it, but I didn't find any more details than the text above (which seems surprising, as I would think this would be a common question).  My main concern is processes starving other processes, so I'm wondering if preemption occurs on timer interrupts with VOLUNTARY.  Of course the more info the better, so I'm wondering what the other preemtion points might be.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174955/what-is-voluntary-preemption

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769768/why-disabling-interrupts-disables-kernel-preemption-and-how-spin-lock-disables-p?rq=1

Comment: Thanks -- I came across the first article, but it still has a vague quote: "while doing kernel things".  It mentions IO as an example, but unfortunately doesn't go on to mention other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [this link to a mailing list](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg26233.html) has the answer.

Which is that `might_sleep()` and `might_resched()` become voluntary preemption points. Enabling PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY makes it call the function `cond_resched()`.

And no, voluntary preemption does not occur on interrupts. That would be full preemption, which checks on each interrupt and if the kernel not flagged to block preemption, it switches to the highest priority task.